# directional derivative and diffrentiablity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Assum $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R $ , define f such that:

$f (x, y) = \begin{cases} 
\frac {X^2y} {x^3-y^2} , &  if & x^3 \neq y^2 \\
0 , &  if &  x^3 =y^2
\end{cases}$

We want to show that for each $ z\in \mathbb R^2 $ , the directional derivative of f at (0,0) in direction of z exists. 
But f is not diffrentiable at (0,0).

My idea: 
For directional derivative We should prove :

$\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{f (tx, ty)-f (0,0)}{t}=0 . \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{f (tx, ty)}{t}=0  \\$

I have these options:
x=y=0  or t=0 $\Rightarrow \text {limit is equal to zero.}\\ OR  $
(tx)^3=(ty)^2 $\Rightarrow t=\frac {y^2} {x^3}  $ then limit is equal to zero ? (Not sure) $ 
Is this enough?  Or l am missing something.

About diffrentiablity at (0,0). I was thinking to prove that (0,0) is an isolated point. But couldn't prove it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the second question: Actually $f$ isn't even continuous at $(0,0).$ Even though we've set $f=0$ on the curve $y^2=x^3,$ it still causes problems. Examine $f$ on a curve different from, but close to, $y^2=x^3.$ The curve $y^2 = x^3+ x^4$ comes to mind.